# How to add Amazon ECS to non default VPC I have already created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have created VPC and added Amazon RDS to it. Now I want to add ECS in this VPC and push my Docker container. My container is React web app and Flask server which I want to communicate with Amazon RDS. I have passed through a great deal of ECS documentation but still can’t do this. Any help or guidance will be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you create your ECS service. One way was already provided by @ThiagoDaAnunciação.

Other ways are (for **FARGATE**):

- in CloudFormation there is [NetworkConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html#cfn-ecs-service-networkconfiguration)
- in CLI there is [--network-configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/create-service.html)

For **EC2 launch type**, you specify the VPC and subnets when you create your **container instances**.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is quite simple if I understand your question of course.

I you are using ECS-CLI, what I extremely recommend, and if you don't, here some doc and the installation process:

[AWS ECS-CLI Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-up.html)

[Github doc ECS-CLI](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli)

I think that all of this commands could by fill on AWS ECS console, but I think that using ECS-CLI is so easier so, that is how I do that.

```
ecs-cli configure --cluster YOURCLUSTER --default-launch-type FARGATE --region sa-east-1

ecs-cli up --vpc vpc-6548c10d --subnets subnet-46386800,subnet-6648c10e,subnet-6748c10f  --cluster-config achievemore --ecs-profile achievemore_ecs
```

Hope that it could be helpful for you.